# Get a unique combination from a Table Column using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

For example, I have a data as the following in a column:

[image]

I need to make all possible unique combinations of this in another table in 2 columns using VBA like below:

[image]

Any help on how can I achieve this? Thanks.

PS. The column data is variable. It can have various number of currencies. The above one is just a small example.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example how to find all these permutations. With this you should be able to solve it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindPermutations()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Const fRow As Long = 2 'first row
    Const lRow As Long = 5 'last row

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = fRow To lRow
        For j = i + 1 To lRow
            'print out all permutations
            Debug.Print ws.Cells(i, "A").Value, ws.Cells(j, "A").Value
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**How does it work?**
It uses 2 loops. The first one `i` runs through all rows. The second `j` only from the current `i` row to the last row. This ensures that already found combinations are not used again.

Note that I used constants for `fRow` and `lRow` for an easy demonstration. You might want to change them into variables in a production environment.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. But the problem is, the currencies are not limited. The values may vary. Can you amend it to auto get the last row till the last column value until it founds empty? Hope I am able to clear.

Comment: @AtharK Yes, this is only an example of how to find the permutations technically. There is some work left for you: How to find the last used row in a column was discussed at least 100 times here on Stack Overflow. Should be easy to find.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how your computations is finding the data on which cells? I mean where I should put the data of currencies so it should construct the combinations?

Comment: It takes it from column `"A"` as stated in `ws.Cells(i, "A").Value` first and last rows are defined in the code.

Comment: And where does it print the results?

Comment: In the intermediate window (debug) of the VB editor. If you want to output them into sheet you will need to change that. `ws.Cells(i, "A").Value` is the left side of a combination and `ws.Cells(j, "A").Value` the right side. As I said this is a technical demonstration only. You will need to put in some effort yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for the complete answer as I am not that expert in VBA.

Comment: Well, this is no free code writing service where you can ask what you want and get the whole code for free. This is more like we assist/help you to fix your issue on your own. So you will need to do the work and we only assist. So I suggest you put in some effort yourself, do some research and when you get stuck ask a new question telling where you get an error.

Comment: Will do that. Thanks for your help.